# validate a field's value is greater than another field's value in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working with form validations.

I have two text fields for adding budget. I want to check whether the value of total budget field is greater than that of daily budget in the click event of my submit button .I am using a form validation jquery plugin for validating my form. I want to customize that jquery with greaterthan rule.How can I  validate a field's value is greater than another field's value in php and javascript..
I have tried with a method for greaterthan

Javascript:

```
method:
greaterThan: function(value, element, param)
    {
    var target = $(param);
    return value <= target.val();
    }
```

and

```
rules: {
            totalbudget: {
                   required: true,
                   greaterThan:"#daylybudget"
        },
```

But this is not working! How can I accomplish this?

Comment: when are you comparing them? after they are valid entries, after a submit button is clicked? Where is the rest of the code? Would you consider using jquery (javascript on steroids)

Comment: I have two text fields for adding budget. I want to check whether the value of total budget field is greater than that of daily budget in the click event of my submit  button .I am using a form validation jquery plugin for validating my form. I want to customize that jquery with greaterthan rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
var val1 = $('#textboxid1').val();
var val2 = $('#textboxid2').val();
var val3 = $('#textboxid3').val();

$('#submitbutton').click(function(){

if((val1 > val2) && (val2 > val3))
{

//prceed further
}
else 
{
alert('alert message');
}

});
```

NOTE: You need to include jquery before this code..

Comment: There's no `JQuery` tag.

Comment: @Vucko Who said there is one?

Comment: @TraianTatic nobody said that there is one. But this answer requires `JQuery` which the OP didn't put as a tag. He put `JavasScript` and `PHP` so obviously he's not looking for a `JQuery` solution.

Comment: @Vucko You should start reading the OP's question, not only the tags he placed. :)

Comment: @TraianTatic well, I'm processing the questions firstly by it's tags, then code, and then the text. But okey, my bed :)
You can always edit/suggest edit the OP if you see that something is missing/not correct :)

Answer (score 0):

First, javascript is client side, php is server side. Depending on the type of validation you need you can implement one of these validations or even both of them.

Considering the following form

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_num" id="first_num" />
    <input type="text" name="second_num" id="second_num" />
    <input type="text" name="third_num" id="third_num" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send & validate" onclick="validate()" />
</form>
```

Here's a javascript way of doing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var value1;
        var value2;
        var value3;
        value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first_num').value);
        value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second_num').value);
        value3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('third_num').value);
        if (value1 > value2 && value2 > value3)
        {
            //we're ok
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Values are not as they should be");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

As for the php side:

```
<?php
    $value1 = $_POST['first_num'];
    $value2 = $_POST['second_num'];
    $value3 = $_POST['third_num'];

    if ($value1 > $value2 && $value2 > $value3)
    {
        //do whatever you want because the values are as you wish
    }
    else
    {
        //the values are not as they should be
    }
?>
```

Keep in mind that usually, for this kind of validation, javascript might be just enough.